# Through (inclusive/exclusive)

Tags: word-usage

When someone says, "I will be out of the office through 5/24/17," include the 5/24/17 date or does it mean that they are returning on 5/24/17?

Answer (score 6):

"Through" is always inclusive. In fact, in this sort of context it is usually chosen *because* it's always inclusive, while "till"/"until" (the other main choice) may or may not include the last day.

Refs: [Merriam-Webster #4](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/through), [Dictionary.com #7](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/through).

Answer (score -1):

> I will be out of the office through 5/24/17

includes 5/24/17, they may be returning to town on the 24th, but they will not be in the office.  The first day they would be back in the office is the 25th.

The person may have also said

> I will be out of the office through 5/24/17 inclusive

to prevent any ambuguity.

Answer (score -1):

It is a bit ambiguous. The relevant meaning of "through" here is "during the whole period of". If I say that "my friend slept through the movie", that means my friend was asleep during the *entire* movie, including the end. Similarly, if someone were to say that they will be on vacation through May 24th, then they would return on May 25th.

On the other hand, if someone were to say that they will be on vacation **until** May 24th, then they would return on the 24th, not the 25th.

To avoid ambiguity, it's often a good idea to explicitly clarify:

> I'll be out of the office through May 24th, and returning to work on May 25th.