# "Through July 28th" - is this grammatically valid or just a colloquialism?

Tags: grammar, american-english, transatlantic-differences

I was just watching [this video](https://youtu.be/WyVCd3Ds5Mw?t=176). At the end, they are promoting a t-shirt and say:

> "The offer is valid through July 28th"

Now, I've heard this said before but never really given it much thought. It's not really used in the UK, we'd just say:

> The offer is valid until...
>
> The offer is valid up to, and including,...
>
> The offer is valid [date 1] through to [date 2].

There is a similar question here: [Through (inclusive/exclusive)](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/129880/through-inclusive-exclusive)

Is is grammatically correct or just an AmE colloquialism?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Through (inclusive/exclusive)](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/129880/through-inclusive-exclusive)

Comment: Is there a reason why you think something you’ve heard used before isn’t grammatical?

Comment: It's a word that's listed in dictionaries. Per [Merriam-Webster's](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/through) definition of sense 4 C of the preposition: "to and including // Monday through Friday." If one date *through* another date is fine, then omitting the first date is simply a way of using a phrase that's open-ended. So long as it's said before the end date, it will still be correct.

Comment: It just does not sound right to ommit "to", to my ear as a native BrE speaker

Comment: @Bee As a native AmE, "through to" sounds entirely wrong.

Comment: @Matt that'd kinda why I'm asking. I wonder why both of us have an aversion to the other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This use of "through" with a date, meaning "up to and including" that date, is very common and wholly natural in US English. I gather it is less common in UK English.

Some examples:

> - I will be on vacation through Thursday.
> - He will be in a meeting through 2 pm.
> - The store will be open through the 21st.
> - The play will run though October 15th.

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/through) gives "to and including" as sense 4 C, and I see no reason to think this is not grammatical.